# Native Android/iOS app or javascript/html/css

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

I would like to make an app for Android and iOS:

Consider a feature-similar app like [Uber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab) using the map and its location features, widgets on the map, login screen, camera and WIFI information (what wifi hotspots are available and if it’s private or free, etc). The user also needs to use either paypal or credit card.

1. What would be better: using HTML5, CSS and javascript or developing a separate app for Android and iOS? Or maybe developing in C++ and creating two UIs for Android and iOS?
2. Are frameworks (like phonegap) best for high-level apps like games that don't need too much access to native features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best thing to do is develop a separate app for Android and iOS.**

Making them separate you can maintain the high performance for both operating systems.

And obviously Android and ios have guidelines regarding the graphics very different. So if your goal is to get high performance from your app, you should definitely make two apps for the two operating systems. Instead, if your goal is to have an app to be published in a short time you can make a hybrid application.

**I think this 'true image' will clarify your ideas**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from personal experience (working in parallel on iOS and Android right now with some mapping apps):
 - Android's ties to GooglePlay for all mapping services are a big headache
 - Implementation of GoogleMaps SDK on iOS is NOT the same as on Android

If you want a very similar look and feel for both platforms; go with web-based.